# Misleading realtime update bar

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, live-refresh

[image]

In the edit-realtime-update thingy, a clickable gray bar shows up (that reloads the edit), along with a clickable link that leads to the revision.

Well, the fact is, when you have a shiny blue link, you don't realize that the gray bar is clickable.

I ended up clicking the blue link and being redirected to the revision history. At first, I thought it was a complete bug, but after some pondering I realised that the gray bar must have been clickable as well.

Nesting clickable items is probably bad UX ([We'll find out soon enough](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/20467/nesting-clickable-items)). Especially when one of them is a link--it "masks" the clickable-ness (whatever the term is) of the parent item.

Could we make this clearer? It's a minor <sub><sup>[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)</sup></sub>
, but it ought to be easy to fix. Maybe:

> an edit has been made to this post, click to load. (Or see [revision history])

or something of that sort.

What say?

Comment: I got confused by that too, I thought it was just because I'm easily confused. +1

Comment: @vasco I was afraid this was going to be shot down as "too trivial" or "you're just stupid". Good to know there are others with the same problem :) Now we just have to sort out if the both of us are stupid or not ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text has been changed to

> an edit has been made to this post; click to load

A link to the revision history was an attempt to be too helpful when trying to determine what changed.  This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Comment: I got this bar when I edited and answer. I thought that someone else had stomped on my edit. Can it be suppressed when you've just completed an edit?

Comment: @ChrisF: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130169/live-notification-shown-for-own-edits

Comment: @Manishearth - cheers, upvoted that

Comment: @Geoff [looks like UX.SE agrees](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/20492/11396)

Answer (score 15):

Why do we need the link to the revision history at all? Why not just load the new post and if they want to see the revision history, they can click on that convenient link "edited *16 secs ago*" to view it... Isn't that what the link is there for? Why so repetitive?

Also, linking to the revision history when it's loading an edit from within the 5 minute grace period would be completely useless, as there would be nothing but the original post there! Change it to:

> an edit has been made to this post; click to load

Nice and simple and matches the rest. :D

Comment: Yep. That's what I thought initially, though I felt that they may have a good reason for doing so. Usually it's convenient to know what's _changed_ in a post. But yeah, they can click the "edited ... ago" thingy. +1

Comment: Oh no! Please don't introduce a run-on sentence; the same message is shown on _English Language & Usage_.

Answer (score 3):

Additional issue: If you were editing the post yourself in the same time, and you click on the shiny blue link that appears, all your current changes to the post are lost.

Making sure you don't lose anything when clicking on the grey bar would be a good thing. I don't know if the problem also occurs, I didn't had an opportunity to test or "endure" that yet.

(Note: I'm not asking for an automatic merge of the new revision with your own current edit,… although this would be neat.)

Comment: Good point. Maybe you could make this a separate meta post? (I'd +1, but I've reached the limit)

Comment: The only issue I can confirm is related to the blue link. If it is decided to remove it, then this issue disappears altogether. If the issue also occurs with a click on the bar, then I'll open a separate meta post.

Comment: Aah. No problem, carry on :)