# Live notification shown for own edits

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits

When editing an answer, the "new revision" message is shown for a short moment. This makes no sense because the revision you just created is automatically displayed anyway.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127513/1-more-comment-when-you-submit-a-comment (identical backend issue actually, just that the frontend issue is different)

Comment: Most likely same bug as [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126489/the-add-show-x-more-comments-showing-itself-after-posting-a-comment)