# An edit to this answer has been made

Tags: bug, edits, live-refresh, grace-period, web-sockets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Misleading realtime update bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130153/misleading-realtime-update-bar)

I got the above notification for this answer: [C# - clarifying 'where T:new()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296923/c-sharp-where-tnew-please-help-me-to-clarify/10296952#10296952)

Clicking it took me to the revisions page, where it showed no edits!
Is the notification kicking in for ninja edits?

Comment: Yep, five minutes grace period - not logged anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's only if you click the revisions link. [Which is, fortunately, gone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130153/misleading-realtime-update-bar/130210#130210)

So this is fixed via collateral damage :)

Comment: By 'gone' I mean 'will be gone the moment the devs push a build'